# How do I get advanced Video Modes in assembly?

Tags: assembly, video

I know the int 10h style of getting video modes. But I found higher quality video modes that require a 16 bit register (fxp. 110h = Standard VGA 24bit color). Is there a function for it or do I need a interrupt. btw. I'm making my example OS. (and this is for graphical interfaces)

Comment: It goes into register AX.  Did you see this?  http://www.wagemakers.be/english/doc/vga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the video BIOS (INT 10h, AH=0) internally programs the video hardware by writing values to the video controller using "in" and "out" assembler instructions.

By directly programming the video controller (by writing values using "in" and "out") you may create "self-defined" video modes that do not have any number at all.

All the video modes defined by the BIOS have numbers 0-0FFh so no number 110h exists.

However the graphics card BIOSs that support a special mode (such as 640x480x24 bit) do not use the same video mode code for this mode (so it may be AL=50h on one video card and AL=60h on another one).

Therefore the "VESA extensions" have been defined which use a different method of setting the video mode. They use different numbers in the range 100h-1FFh for standardized and 200h-3FFh for vendor-defined modes. Not all BIOSs support these extensions. I think most modern "real" BIOSs will support them but maybe some emulators like DOSbox do not support these functions. In this case you have no chance to get this video mode.

By the way: 110h is 640x480x15bits; 24bits would be 112h.

The functions used to access these modes are INT 10h, AX=4F00h-4F0Ch. For most BIOS and MS-DOS interrupts you'll find a good description in "Ralph Brown's interrupt list": The link for the page about INT 10h is: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm.

The video mode is set the following way (see the link above on how to use each function):

- Use AX=4F00h to check if VESA extensions are present at all and to get the capabilities
- Use AX=4F01h to get information about the video mode (e.g. memory segment, page granularity and page size)
- Use AX=4F02h to actually set the video mode
- While accessing the video memory use AX=4F05h to change the video page

The video pages (with a page size and page granularity) are necessary because the memory area from 0A000h:0000h to 0A000h:0FFFFh only represents 64KiB but the memory required for such modes is much more than 64KiB. Using function AX=4F05h you define which 64KiB of the much larger video memory you want to access.

Comment: Most information about the VBE-Bios can be found in the public document "vbe3.pdf" from vesa.org (need register/login). We can divide all VBE bioses into two different categories, the vbe bios version 1.xx on one side and the vbe bios version 2 and version 3 on the other side. For version 1 we can use the standard table of VBE-modenumbers. Starting with VBE 2 we have to use the modetable that comes within the VBE-bios. The far pointer of the modelist can be found in the buffer+0Eh of function 4F00h. I prefer to use the linear frambuffer(LFB). LFB address=Mode info buffer+28h of function 4F01h.